# Determine radius of convergence of this series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need help with this exercise.

$\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}x}$

By the criterion of ratio

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left |\frac{1+n^{2}x}{1+(n+1)^{2}x}\right|=1$$

Some ideas to help me solve this exercise?

Other question: When the exercise asks me for the interval of uniform convergence, how can I calculate that? Because I know how to find the interval of absolute convergence, but not that.

Comment: Your question is NOT clear..Please edit your question properly.

Comment: I'm a little confused, excuse my level of English. 
I wanted to know that if by the criterion of reason, if the limit gives me 1, it means that the radius is 1, because I understand that if the limit gives 1 there is no information. @S717717

Comment: And also wanted to know how to determine the uniform convergence of that series, I imagine it will be via epsilon. @S717717

Comment: If you have done one complex variable the radius of convergence is the distance to the closest pole of the function.

Answer (score 3):

As for the original series, notice that $$\dfrac{1}{1+n^2x}<\dfrac{1}{n^2x}=\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$
so that the sum (for $x>0$ at least) $$0<\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+n^2x}<\dfrac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$
For $x<0$, the argument is pretty similar. The only problem is at $x=0$, we have $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} 1\to\infty$.

Note that the ratio test (as you saw) gives inconclusive results. We can also check this with Mathematica with the code: SumConvergence[1/(1+x*n^2),n]